# "We tried to sign in to your microsoft account, but something went wrong" in Minecraft for Windows 10

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, windows-10

In minecraft v1.16.201 when I try to log in to my Microsoft Account I keep getting this message:

"We tried to sign in to your microsoft account, but something went wrong"

My os is Windows 10 Pro Versión 1909 (18363.1256)

Any suggestion?

[image: Minecraft Error]

Comment: For anyone else who sees this in the future try restarting Minecraft that usually fixes it for me

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got to fix the problem. Open  >Powershell with admin privileges and execute:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```